# health care program

Tags: python, classes

In this program, I'm going to take some information about student's height, weight, and age and return the average of all of them to compare. there are 2 classes to compare and the program works fine but I want to know, is there any way to improve this program and make it better?

```
information = []
for i in range(8):
    information.append(input().split())

information = [[int(x) for x in line] for line in information]



class Student_A:

    def __init__(self, age, height, weight, age_b, height_b, weight_b):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.age_b = age_b
        self.height_b = height_b
        self.weight_b = weight_b

    def get_info(self):
        a = (sum(self.age) / len(self.age))
        b = (sum(self.height) / len(self.height))
        c = (sum(self.weight) / len(self.weight))
        e = (sum(self.age_b) / len(self.age_b))
        f = (sum(self.height_b) / len(self.height_b))
        g = (sum(self.weight_b) / len(self.weight_b))

        yield a
        yield b
        yield c  
        yield e  
        yield f
        yield g 

        if b == f and c == g:
            print('Same')
        elif b == f:
            if c < g:
                print('A')
            else:
                print('B')
        elif b > f:
            print('A')
        else:
            print('B')

class_a = Student_A(information[1], information[2], information[3], information[5], information[6], information[7])
class_a = class_a.get_info()
for item in class_a:
    print(item)
```

input should be like this :

```
# inputs must be entered line by line not every single number

5 # number of students
16 17 15 16 17
180 175 172 170 165
67 72 59 62 55
5
15 17 16 15 16
166 156 168 170 162
45 52 56 58 47
```

output should be like this :

```
16.2
172.4
63.0
15.8
164.4
51.6
A # the best class
```

Comment: my bad sorry let me fix it

Comment: it should work right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, the `Student_A` class is a strange creature:
(1) it stores lists of ages, heights, and weights for two groups of students;
(2) it computes the age, height, and weight averages each of the groups; and
(3) it does some logic to compare the averages. If we ask what meaningful
real-world entity a `Student_A` instance is supposed to represent, there isn't
one. That suggests that there is a problem with the design.

Here's a class that does make sense in the real world:

```
class StudentGroup:

    def __init__(self, ages, heights, weights):
        # Note the use of plural variable names.
        # Don't call it an "age" if it's really a list of ages.
        self.ages = ages
        self.heights = heights
        self.weights = weights
```

Each `StudentGroup` instance would hold the ages, heights, and weights for
**one group**. The program would create two instances of the class and
then perform the other calculations and comparisons.

The class needs a way to obtain the averages. This is a good use case for a
`@property` and the standard library's `statistics` module.

```
from statistics import mean

class StudentGroup:

    @property
    def avg_age(self):
        return mean(self.ages)

    # Do the same for height and weight.
```

To compare the groups, you just need to implement two methods on the class, and
include the `total_ordering` decorator. It allows you to directly
compares two instances of a class in various ways (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`),
provided that you implement the two methods shown below.

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class StudentGroup:

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            self.avg_height == other.avg_height and
            self.avg_weight == other.avg_weight
        )

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # You can implement this one. Return True if self < other.
```

Regarding input parsing, I suggest that you organize the parsing to align with
the program's larger goal: don't collect 8 input lines; instead collect 4 input
lines twice. Also, put all of your code inside functions:

```
def line_to_ints(line):
    # A utility function to parse one line of user input.
    return [int(x) for x in line.split()]

def main():
    # Create two StudentGroup instances.
    sgs = []
    for _ in range(2):
        # Get lines of input from user. Don't parse here.
        lines = [input() for _ in range(4)]

        # Parse the needed lines into a list-of-list of ints.
        params = [line_to_ints(line) for line in lines[1:]]

        # Create a new StudentGroup instance.
        sgs.append(StudentGroup(*params))

    # Compare them.
    msg = (
        'Same' if sgs[0] == sgs[1] else
        'A'    if sgs[0] >  sgs[1] else
        'B'
    )

    # Report.
    print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: is it ok to do the printing inside a function? because once you said to do the printing outside the function

Comment: @Xus Printing inside functions is fine -- definitely the way to go. The key question is what type of function is it? Functions with computations should not print; they should return data or modify data. Printing should occur in the outer shell of a program inside of a function that doesn't do anything complicated (usually that means the `main()` function). To review my own code in the answer above, one could argue that most of the work should be delegated to two helper functions: `get_user_input()` and `parse()`. But still print in `main()`.

Comment: thank you I got it

Answer (score 2):

A critical rule to remember about coding is: If a bunch of your lines look basically the same, you can probably simplify your program using for-loops.

This is true for your code as well. If, instead of storing all the information in different variables, you just store them in a single tuple for each student, you can greatly shorten your code using for-loops.

```py
information = []
for i in range(8):
    information.append(input().split())

information = [[int(x) for x in line] for line in information]



class Student_A:

    def __init__(self, age, height, weight, age_b, height_b, weight_b):
        self.student_a = (age, height, weight)
        self.student_b = (age_b, height_b, weight_b)

    def get_info(self):
        abc = []
        efg = []
        for i in range(len(self.student_a)): 
            abc.append(sum(self.student_a[i]) / len(self.student_a[i]))
            efg.append(sum(self.student_b[i]) / len(self.student_b[i]))

        for info in abc:
            yield info
        for info in efg:
            yield info

        if abc[1] == efg[1] and abc[2] == efg[2]:
            print('Same')
        elif abc[1] == efg[1]:
            if abc[2] < efg[2]:
                print('A')
            else:
                print('B')
        elif abc[1] > efg[1]:
            print('A')
        else:
            print('B')

class_a = Student_A(information[1], information[2], information[3], information[5], information[6], information[7])
class_a = class_a.get_info()
for item in class_a:
    print(item)
```

Note that `for i in range(len(self.student_a)):` only works because `self.student_a` and `self.student_b` are defined to be the same length. It just does the `sum / len` calculation for every piece of information.

Also, instead of yielding every variable, now just iterate through `abc` and `efg`!

The last complicated if-statement also needs to use indexes instead of variables, but thanks to my informative list names it should be simple to understand.

If there's anything else you would like to clarify, feel free to ask me!

Note: If you want to shorten your code even more, you can just have 1 tuple for both students. In my opinion, though, that's not particularly readable.